# Database structure: Relational table with more columns or relational table to a relational table?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, mariadb

I am designing a database on a logical level to later pass it on for programmers to deliver. I am only superficially familiar with how they work, so I am struggling to phrase my problem succintly. Here's my problem:

I have a table named MEANINGS.

I have a table named WORDS.

I have relational table named M-to-W.

I have a table named GRAMMAR.

**Words** can have multiple **meanings**, **meanings** can have multiple **words**. But I also wanna add **grammar**. I could just add a row in WORDS, but sometimes a word behaves differently depending on meanings (like the past tense is “He hanged himself” for suicide and “He hung a picture on the wall” for putting). Hence, I see two solutions on a logical level:

1. GRAMMAR could be linked with the M-to-W relational table with another relational table, referencing entire relationships (certain meanings of certain words have specified forms).
2. GRAMMAR items could be referenced by M-to-W in additional row.

I have only created relational databases with Django/MariaDB (pretty much automatically), so I don't know if these can have more than two columns. I don't know if referencing pairs of properties is possible.

Is any of these solutions possible, or is there a better practice to handle this kind of structural problem? Is using composite keys easier? Please assume keeping words and meanings in separate tables is necessary.

Comment: Rather call `M-to-W` a relationship table than a relational table. If you have a first-order logical model, all of your tables are relational tables. Think of relation as a synonym for table, but with some extra rules, like no duplicate rows/columns and order of rows/columns don't matter.

Comment: Okay, thanks, didn't know that!

Comment: In the relational model, relations (tables) represent n-ary relation(ship)s. You need to read some book(s) on info modeling, the relational model & DB design. [Here are some I can endorse.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007275/3404097) Re whether you can or should replace a ternary relation(ship) by others falls under "dependency theory" which involves "normalization to higher NFs (normal forms)".

Comment: @philipxy thanks, will now proceed to reading them!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composite Primary key vs additional "ID" column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588304/composite-primary-key-vs-additional-id-column)

Comment: PS See [this answer, its PS 3 & its question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45557994/3404097) re binaryrelation(ship)/table on an associative entity & a non-associattive entity vs ternary in ER modeling and re binary instead of ternary via id PKs/FKs.

Comment: The questions you referred me to were very instructive, but I think that my question is more about weighing two possibilities against each other.

Answer (score 2):

*Before* defining the schema, decide what data you have, and how it will be put into the database.

*And* decide what you want out of the database.

Give the programmers that info, *not* the specifications of the tables.  Let them figure out the best way to structure the schema.

If none of them have any database background, then there is a learning curve.  Answers from this forum will only help you out of one pitfall after another.  Please take the time to get at least one programmer trained.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I know what data I have and how it will be put there. But I don't have any programmers yet; I am preparing a specification. Is solution to that problem indeed so specfic case-dependent?

Comment: It _may_ be better to have a single table for everything, rather than a 3-headed many-to-many mapping table.  Can't tell without trying it.  (I don't know if Django has a restriction.)

Comment: Django is not an absolute given here, but while words & grammar can be groupped up, meanings _must_ be separate.