# Relational Database Design Query

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, relational

I am a novice programmer, currently attempting to create a Java EE web application for a dissertation project.

I am currently designing that relational database for my web application and  I have created an E-R Diagram for the database:

[image: E-R Diagram]

My query relates to the TeachingClass table.  Each class can be taught by one or more Employees (normally a max of 3) and each class can contain one or more pupils (normally around 25).  Each teaching class relates to exactly one course, however, there might be a several TeachingClass running simultaneously for each particular course.

From my E-R diagram can someone please confirm that I have set the Teaching Class table correctly, or should I be using two additional joining tables:

- One table between TeachingClass and Pupil
- One table between TeachingCLass and Employee.

Thanks in advance for any feedback/recommendations provided.

Comment: Hi. Constraints (FKs, cardinalities) fall out of designs after you have decided what entities & relationships you need. First just find which (each getting a table) you need to capture your entire state. Every relationship should be described by a statement saying how its values (& entities so identified) are related. Give a reference for the (so-called) ER method you are using. PS Please use text for text (including in tables & ER diagrams). Here, give minimal DDL (possibly pseudo-code). (Minimal) images should be supplemental. If you have the rep don't use links for anything necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [relationships between 3 entities in ER diagram--is a ternary enough or are 2 binaries also needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45551388/relationships-between-3-entities-in-er-diagram-is-a-ternary-enough-or-are-2-bin)